# Getting Nullpointer exception while doing datadriven through excel in Serenity BDD (Junit)

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, serenity-bdd

Getting this in stacktrace while executing 1 daradriven test through commandline (Serenity - junit).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.TestClassRunnerForParameters.getName(TestClassRunnerForParameters.java:73)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:394)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:123)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:401)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.configureRunner(RunnerBuilder.java:81)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:72)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
```

Comment: I was using @Testprovider annotation and SerenityParameterizedRunner.class annotation at the class level. I feel there is some issue with it. I managed to write data driven using another approach then. First read data data through excel and store data in Object[][] array and loop through it using advanced for loop to take data and send it respective fields. In this we don't require SerenityParameterizedRunner.class. just used SerenityRunner.class